# How to create fragment without action bar in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabhost

Hi all I have to create fragment with out action bar. Like this

[image]

In this picture I created Lienarlayout and placed that image in center. Below of that I want to create 4 fragments like projects,calender,filter and search. I searched a lot and tried by many codes but all the fragments has created with action bar. But i need to create fragments without action bar. How can I create that? Can anybody tell me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ActionBars are actually components of your Activity objects and not your Fragments.  (Take a look at the [ActionBar documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)).  If your app is API level >= 11, your Activity objects will have ActionBars by default.  These are set by the SDK-provided Holo theme.  You can remove the ActionBar from the Activity to which your fragments are attached.

In order to do so, modify the Holo theme.  Create a styles resource like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then in your manifest you should associate the modified theme with the Activity that you want to be ActionBar-less:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.yourproject.activity.NoActionBarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
```